# Dynamically create JSON object for datareader results, regardless of what they look like?

Tags: c#, json, datareader

Right now I'm using `Newtonsoft.json` with my `OdbcConnection` and manually creating objects for each query I run.  It looks something like this:

Classes:

```
public class payload
{
    public string id;
    public string type;
    public DateTime timestmap;
    public object data;
}
public class resultPhrLastTime
{
    public string facilityId;
    public string type;
    public string time;
}
```

Code:

```
payload result = new payload();
var resultList = new List<resultPhrLastTime>();
result.id = "someid";

//connection stuff

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var t = new resultPhrLastTime();
            //if (verbose) log(reader[0].ToString());
            t.facilityId = reader[0].ToString();
            t.type = reader[1].ToString();
            t.time = reader[2].ToString();
            resultList.Add(t);
        }

    result.data = resultList;
    result.timestmap = DateTime.Now;
    result.type = "complex";
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

This works fine, but every time I add a new query to my app (of which there will be many) I have to create a new custom class if the data looks different at all.

I would like to find a way to convert the entire `reader` object to JSON regardless of the format, so it may look like this:

> SQL Result:
>
> ```
> 2814814
> ```
>
> JSON:
>
> ```
> result: {
>    timestamp: 2016-09-10 8:15,
>    data: { '2814814' }
> }
> ```

or it may look like this:

> SQL Result:
>
> ```
> Apple  | 59    
> Orange | 17
> ```
>
> JSON:
>
> ```
> result: {
>    timestamp: 2016-09-10 8:15,
>    data: {[ 
>       'Apple':'59',
>       'Orange':'17'
>    ]}
> }
> ```

Or there could be 5 columns...

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could build a function that creates the Json-string from your result-set if it is as simple as the ones above. Json is really just a formatted string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the dynamic type of c#

```
public class payload
{
    public string id;
    public string type;
    public DateTime timestmap;
    public dynamic data;
}


payload result = new payload();
var resultList = new List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();
result.id = "someid";

//connection stuff

while (reader.Read())
{

    var t = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    for (var i = 0; i<reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        t[reader.GetName(i)] = reader[i];
    }
    resultList.Add(t);
}

result.data = resultList;
result.timestmap = DateTime.Now;
result.type = "complex";
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

The dynamic type is handled by JsonConvert automatically.

You can also make the data field of the payload to a dynamic to handle single field results like in your first JSON example.

Comment: That's perfect! Followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395050/error-with-datareader-when-value-from-timestamp-column-is-null  But it might be [tag:intersystems-cache] specific.